# Which 'as' is paired with 'talk of' in 'talking of a sentence as being true under such-and-such conditions as a shorthand way'?

Tags: meaning

> Having made this general point, however, we will follow the widespread
> practice of talking of a sentence **as** being true under such-and-such
> conditions **as** a shorthand way of saying that the proposition asserted
> by the sentence under those conditions would be true.

I think it should be

> Having made this general point, however, we will follow the widespread
> practice of **talking of** [a sentence as being true under such-and-such
> conditions ] **as** [a shorthand way of saying that the proposition asserted
> by the sentence under those conditions would be true].

So, in the sentence "a sentence as being true under such-and-such conditions ", can this 'as' be deleted?

Comment: Since  the word "as" appears twice, please type out the sentence in the form you think is possible, so there's no confusion about which "as" you are referring to.

Comment: I think your subdivision delimiters are wrong! The "internal" component is *talking of a sentence as being true under such-and-such conditions*. Suppose that specific action has already been referred to earlier in the conversation, allowing us to refer back to it as ***this***. That gives us *...we will follow **this** as a shorthand way of saying...* But the text is clumsily-written anyway, so it's not worth spending too much time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answers your question. Yes, you can omit or include the [as] shown below:

Having made this general point, however, we will follow the widespread practice of talking of a sentence **[as]** being true under such-and-such conditions as a shorthand way of saying that the proposition asserted by the sentence under those conditions would be true.

Comment: I might also substitute "talking of a sentence" with *talking about a sentence* or *speaking of a sentence*.